# FIFO files and read/write

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I've been trying to get some insight on FIFO and this low level I/O before my laboratories on monday and I came to this situation I don't quite understand.

**The program should:**

Server:

- creates FIFOs,
- sends 5 messages: "Message #i", with interval of 5 sec,
- deletes FIFOs,

Client:

- reads from FIFO and displays the message,
- terminates if there was no msg for 6 seconds,

And it does communicate however, client is displaying not exactly what I did send him, and more importantly, seems to be reading from the beginning every time a new msg arrives. I've been trying to figure out, for quite a while, and it just doesn't seem to match what the documentation said... Please help! :(

**server**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{       
    int s2c, c2s, i; 
    char fifo_name1[] = "/tmp/fifo1";
    char fifo_name2[] = "/tmp/fifo2";
    char msg[80], buf[10];
    struct stat st;

    // if no fifos, create 'em
    if (stat(fifo_name1, &st) != 0)
        mkfifo(fifo_name1, 0666);
    if (stat(fifo_name2, &st) != 0)
        mkfifo(fifo_name2, 0666);

    s2c= open(fifo_name1, O_WRONLY);
    c2s= open(fifo_name2, O_RDONLY);

    // start sending messages, with 5s interval
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Message #%d \n", i);

        strcat(msg, "Message #"); 
        strcat(msg, itoa(i, buf, 10));
        strcat(msg, "\0"); 

        write(s2c, msg, strlen(msg)+1);

        sleep(5);
    }

    // delete fifos
    unlink(fifo_name1);
    unlink(fifo_name2);
    printf("server exit successfully");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**client**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int c2s, s2c, c=0;
    char buf[10];

    char fifo_name1[] = "/tmp/fifo1";
    char fifo_name2[] = "/tmp/fifo2";
    s2c= open(fifo_name1, O_RDONLY);
    c2s= open(fifo_name2, O_WRONLY);

    // receive messages
    while (1)
    {
        if (read(s2c, &buf, sizeof(char)*10) > 0)
        {
            printf("%s \n", buf);
            c=0;
        }
        sleep(1);
        c++;    
        if (c>6) 
            break;
    }

    printf("client exit successfully");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcat(msg, "Message #");` always appends to the end of the string already in `msg`, and the string is never reset during the loop. Replace it with `strcpy(msg, "Message #");` to start each new message from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now! :D Looks like I was looking for mistake in a completly wrong place, shame on me :(